# Expired JWT Token - How to refresh token

Tags: angularjs, symfony, jwt, json-web-token

I am developing a mobile application, and I realize that my token has a limited duration. I am using a Symfony server, which has a function to refresh me token:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/refresh", name="api_refresh")
 */
public function refreshTokenAction(Request $request)
{
    if(!$request->headers->has('Authorization')) {
        return;
    }

    $extractor = new AuthorizationHeaderTokenExtractor(
        'Bearer',
        'Authorization'
    );

    $token = $extractor->extract($request);

    $encoder = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder');

    $data = $encoder->decode($token);

    if(!$data){
        return;
    }

    $username = $data['mail'];

    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Benevole')
        ->findOneBy(['mail' => $username]);

    $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')
        ->encode(['mail' => $user->getMail()]);

    // Return genereted tocken
    return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token]);

}
```

I use this server with an application in AngularJS, in which I call my server in this way:

```
var refreshToken = function(idPatient){
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem('token'); // current valid token
    return $http({
           method  : 'GET',
           url     : url + '/refresh',
           headers : {Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token},
       }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.data);
        return result.data;
    });
};
```

When I test my function refresh token, clicking a button, it works, the token is refreshed.

I would like to know how I can refresh my token, this automatically, so that the user does not have to disconnect each time, because it is rather restrictive ^^
Should I check my token every time ? Should I put several conditions for the application to find this every time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should accept *only* valid (and non-expired) tokens for refreshment. Assume that it's responsability of the client to refresh the tokens before the expiration date indicated in the [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) claim.

You can call the function to refresh the token periodically, while the use is active in the page.

---

To avoid a token from being refreshed indefinitely, you could, for example, keep the track of the token refreshment by adding two claims to your token (the claim names are up to you):

- `refreshLimit`: Indicates how many times the token can be refreshed.
- `refreshCount`: Indicates how many times the token has been refreshed.

So only refresh the token if the following conditions are true:

- The token is not expired (`exp >= now`).
- The number of times that the token has been refreshed is less than the number of times that the token can be refreshed (`refreshCount < refreshLimit`).

And when refreshing the token:

- Update the expiration date (`exp = now + some-amount-of-time`).
- Increment the number of times that the token has been refreshed  (`refreshCount++`).

Once the token is signed and the signature is verified on server side, the content of the token cannot be tampered by the client.

Comment: Alternatively to `refreshCount` one may introduce the absolute expiration time, a custom property that limits the number of refreshes as well.

Comment: That's another valid approach :)

Comment: Yep, they are the same indeed :-) I also seen people issue a separate long living refresh token that is used to issue the short-living JWT's. In some cases it might be more convenient.

Comment: Thank you @CássioMazzochiMolin